# Adding a photo to my AskDiffernt bio account

Tags: support

How can I add a photo to my AskDifferent account?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to sign up for a [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) account with the same email address you're using for your Ask Different account. You can set the image you want to use for your avatar from your Gravatar account.

Comment: Why is one 'forced' to use gravatar when adding an avatar? I don't like this because I'm against a centralized identification.

Comment: Because Stack Exchange isn't a user-content host. They don't host uploaded images, they don't host profile data, nadda.